# Почему xalan не может найти метод который использует ExpressionContext?

Tags: c#, xslt, xalan

Рассмотрим простой класс:

```
using org.apache.xalan.extensions;

namespace Foo
{
    public static class Extension
    {
        public static string Bar(ExpressionContext context, string baz)
        {
            return "Hello, world!";
        }
    }
}
```

Вот так я пытаюсь его использовать:

```
using javax.xml.transform;
using javax.xml.transform.stream;

public static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = new com.sun.org.apache.xalan.@internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl();

        java.lang.Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(new ikvm.runtime.AppDomainAssemblyClassLoader(typeof(Program).Assembly));
        Transformer t = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource("transform.xslt"));
        t.transform(new StreamSource("doc.xml"), new StreamResult(java.lang.System.@out));
    }
}
```

Входной файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root />
```

Трансформация:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:foo="xalan://cli.Foo.Extension">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="foo:Bar('baz')" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Но в итоге получаю вот такую ошибку:

> ERROR:  'Cannot find external method 'cli.Foo.Extension.bar' (must be public).'
>   FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'

В то же время вызов `java.lang.Class.forName("cli.Foo.Extension").getMethods()` нужный метод находит. В чем дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая проблема в том, что код использует одновременно два разных Xalan: один встроенный в стандартную библиотеку (пакет `com.sun.org.apache.xalan`), второй - установленный отдельно (пакет `org.apache.xalan`). У них разные интерфейсы `ExpressionContext`, которые несовместимы друг с другом.

Вторая проблема - код использует XSLTC (компилирующую разновидность Xalan), который еще (?) не научили распознавать `ExpressionContext`. Нужно использовать интерпретирующую версию.

Вот такой код будет работать:

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = new org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl();

java.lang.Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(new ikvm.runtime.AppDomainAssemblyClassLoader(typeof(Program).Assembly));
Transformer t = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource("transform.xslt"));
t.transform(new StreamSource("doc.xml"), new StreamResult(java.lang.System.@out));
```

Comment: Примечание для отвечающих: у меня-то код заработал, но я все еще не уверен что этот ответ правильный (особенно его часть про XSLTC - такое ощущение что информацию про него в инете намеренно затирают). Так что буду рад альтернативным ответам если есть что добавить.

Comment: `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.@internal.xsltc.trax` - эту часть вам инопланетяни нашептали :-)

Comment: @DigitalCore нет, эту часть я где-то на SO увидел :-) Или в сообщении об ошибке, не помню уже.